# JPA query run into oracle fails, depending on the values, with ORA-00600

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I am working on an application that uses criteria builder to perform search with multiple criteria. There is a bug that when selecting two specific criteria the application crashes. I used the show_sql property to display the query that is being performed in the database.

I am getting this error:

> SQL Error: 600, SQLState: 60000
>
> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kdsgrp1], [], [], [], [],
>   [], [], [], [], [], [], []

the query is the one below:

```
    select count(ves0_.CODE) as col_0_0_
    from
    VES ves0_
  where
            ves0_.STARTDATE<=TO_DATE('29/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    and ves0_.ENDDATE>TO_DATE('29/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    and ves0_.LICENCE_IND='Y'
    and (exists
                (select
                        ves1_.CODE
                    from
                        LICENSES ves1_
                    where
                        ves0_.CODE=ves1_.CODE
                        and nvl(ves1_.LICENSE_DATE_RENEWED, ves1_.LICENSE_DATE_ISSUED)<=TO_DATE('02/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                        and ves1_.LICENSE_DATE_VALID_TO>TO_DATE('02/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                )
            )
    and ves0_.STARTDATE<=TO_DATE('29/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    and ves0_.ENDDATE>TO_DATE('29/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

It seems that the problem is with the dates inside the exists clause.

Some dates are bringing correct results without crashing the application, others like the one above ('02/10/2018') are throwing this error

> [60000][600] ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kdsgrp1], [],
>   [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

when running it on SQL Developer just like the on in the application.

Is there a problem with the query? Why it works for some values and not for others?

Are the data causing the error? I run some other queries and there does not seem to be any differences on data ranging through different dates.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have the same problem with an other query in the same application:

```
select count(ves0_.CODE) as col_0_0_
from
    VES ves0_
where
    ves0_.STARTDATE<=TO_DATE('29/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    and ves0_.ENDDATE>TO_DATE('29/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    and ves0_.UPDATE_IND='RET'
```

I posted that because it is a simpler case. This time when I change the UPDATE_IND the query crashes with the same error.

UPDATE_IND can only take eight different values. I tested all of them and the query runs for six of them and causes ORA-00600 for the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a service request to [Oracle support](https://support.oracle.com/). Seems like you face the bug **Causes and Solutions for ora-600 [kdsgrp1] (Doc ID 1332252.1)**, but you should check at least verify it with your dba.